# minipage next to footnotes tabular

Tags: tables, footnotes, minipage

I have a landscape table. At the bottom I would like to link to some urls referenced via footnotes in the table. To the right of the footnotes, I would also like to include a legend for the table. These are **not** footnotes as the symbols are directly in the table itself (if that makes sense). Below is a mwe. I've copied all the packages I'm using in the document, even though they are not all relevant for this table, in case there are any clashes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}                     % Tables.
\usepackage[figureposition=bottom]{caption}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\title{table mwe}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\section*{Summary of papers}
%\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{cm{3cm}ccccccccccc}
\toprule
 & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Title}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Coauthors}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Venue}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Status}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Pre-}\\\textbf{registered}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Ethical}\\\textbf{Approval}}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Study Design}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Open}\\\textbf{Access}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Online}\\\textbf{Repository}}} \\ \cmidrule(lr){8-11}
 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \makecell{Open\\Materials} & \makecell{Open\\Code} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{Open\\Analyses}} & \makecell{Open\\Data} &  &  \\ \midrule
2 & {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing el} & \makecell{John Smith \\ Jane Doe \\ Pierre Leblanc} & Journal & Published & $\times$ & N/A & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & Gold & Github \protect\footnotemark \\
3 & {Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis} & John Smith & Conference & Published & $\times$  & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\times$  & $\checkmark$ & Green  & \makecell{Github \footnotemark \\ OSF \footnotemark} \\ \addlinespace
4 & Curabitur dictum gravidamauris & John Smith & Conference & Published & $\times$  & $\checkmark$ & N/A & N/A & $\times$  &  $\times$ & $\times$  & Github \footnotemark \\ \addlinespace
5 & Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque & \makecell{John Smith \\ Jane Doe \\ Pierre Leblanc \\ Foo Bar \\ abc xyz} & \makecell[c]{Other \\ Journal} & \makecell[c]{Submitted\\(date)} & $\times$  & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\times$  & $\checkmark$ & $\times$  & - &  \makecell{same as \\ above} \\ \addlinespace
6 & . Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectuset netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egesta & \makecell{Jane Doe \\ John Smith} & - & In Prep & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & N/A & - & - & - & OSF \footnotemark \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\vspace{-0.3cm}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{}
\footnotetext[1]{\url{https://onecvariusorciegetrisus}}
\footnotetext[2]{\url{https://duisnibh micongueeuaccumsaneleifen}}
\footnotetext[3]{\url{https://donecvariusorciegetrisus}}
\footnotetext[4]{\url{https://Namduiligulafringillaa}}
\footnotetext[5]{\url{https://praesentegetsemvelleoultricesbibendum}}
%\vspace{-2cm}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}[]{0.5\textwidth}
\footnotesize
\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0.5pt}
  %\itemsep0em
    \item[$\checkmark$] Available for this paper 
    \item[$\times$] Not possible or not available for this paper 
    \item[N/A] Not Applicable 
    \item[-] Work in progress
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

This produces output like so:
[image]

The `minipage` environment always ends up on a new page. I have tried editing the dimensions, subtracting vspace etc, but nothing works. I also initially had the table itself inside a `minipage` environment to get the footnotes, but changed to the `\footnotemark` `\footnotetext` method in case the two minipages were clashing, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I'm also not sure why there are symbols for the footnotes in this example and not numbers, in the actual table itself this isn't a problem.

How can I position the minipage with the table legend so that it is below the table on the right hand side, parallel to the footnotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the following approach based on `threeparttable`. Using `tabularx`, I also made sure the table does not exceed the available textwidth, as it does in your original code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}                     % Tables.
\usepackage[figureposition=bottom]{caption}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\section*{Summary of papers}
\begin{threeparttable}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
  \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}c>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X*{11}{c}@{}}
    \toprule
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Title}} 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Coauthors}} 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Venue}}} 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Status}} 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Pre-}\\\textbf{registered}}} 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Ethical}\\\textbf{Approval}}} 
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Study Design}} 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Open}\\\textbf{Access}}} 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Online}\\\textbf{Repository}}} \\ 
     \cmidrule(lr){8-11}
    &  &  &  &  &  &  
    & \makecell{Open\\Materials} 
    & \makecell{Open\\Code} 
    & \makecell{Open\\Analyses} 
    & \makecell{Open\\Data} &  &  \\ 
    \midrule
    2 & {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing el} 
      & \makecell{John Smith \\ Jane Doe \\ Pierre Leblanc} 
      & Journal & Published 
      & $\times$ & N/A & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ 
      & Gold & Github \tnote{1} \\
    \addlinespace
    3 & {Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis} 
      & John Smith 
      & Conference & Published 
      & $\times$  & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\times$  & $\checkmark$ 
      & Green  & \makecell{Github \tnote{2} \\ OSF \tnote{3}} \\ 
    \addlinespace
    4 & Curabitur dictum gravidamauris 
      & John Smith 
      & Conference & Published 
      & $\times$  & $\checkmark$ & N/A & N/A & $\times$  &  $\times$ 
      & $\times$  & Github \tnote{4} \\ 
    \addlinespace
    5 & Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque 
      & \makecell{John Smith \\ Jane Doe \\ Pierre Leblanc \\ Foo Bar \\ abc xyz} 
      & \makecell[c]{Other \\ Journal} & \makecell[c]{Submitted\\(date)} 
      & $\times$  & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\times$  & $\checkmark$ & $\times$  
      & - &  \makecell{same as \\ above} \\ 
    \addlinespace
    6 & . Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectuset netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egesta 
      & \makecell{Jane Doe \\ John Smith} 
      & - & In Prep
      & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & N/A & - & - 
      & - & OSF \tnote{5} \\ 
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tablenotes}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
      \item[1]{\url{https://onecvariusorciegetrisus}}
      \item[2]{\url{https://duisnibh micongueeuaccumsaneleifen}}
      \item[3]{\url{https://donecvariusorciegetrisus}}
      \item[4]{\url{https://Namduiligulafringillaa}}
      \item[5]{\url{https://praesentegetsemvelleoultricesbibendum}}
      \smallskip

      \begin{tabular}{rl}
        $\checkmark$ & Available for this paper \\
        $\times$     & Not possible or not available for this paper \\
        N/A          & Not Applicable\\ 
        -            & Work in progress
      \end{tabular}
    \end{multicols}
  \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want real footnotes and multiple `\protect\footnotemark` will utterly confuse `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}                     % Tables.
\usepackage[figureposition=bottom]{caption}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\title{table mwe}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\section*{Summary of papers}
\centering
\footnotesize

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tablefootnotemark}[1]{\textsuperscript{\@fnsymbol{#1}}}
\newcommand{\tablefootnotetext}[1]{\makebox[1em][l]{\textsuperscript{\@fnsymbol{#1}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{c>{\raggedright}m{3cm}ccccccccccc}
\toprule
  & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Title}}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Coauthors}}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Venue}}}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Status}}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Pre-}\\\textbf{registered}}}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Ethical}\\\textbf{Approval}}}
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Study Design}}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Open}\\\textbf{Access}}}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Online}\\\textbf{Repository}}}
\\
\cmidrule(lr){8-11}
  &  &  &  &  &  &
  & \makecell{Open\\Materials}
  & \makecell{Open\\Code}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{Open\\Analyses}}
  & \makecell{Open\\Data}
  &  &
\\
\midrule
2 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing el
  & \makecell{John Smith \\ Jane Doe \\ Pierre Leblanc}
  & Journal
  & Published
  & $\times$
  & N/A
  & $\checkmark$
  & $\checkmark$
  & $\checkmark$
  & $\checkmark$
  & Gold
  & Github\tablefootnotemark{1}
\\
\addlinespace
3 & Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis
  & John Smith
  & Conference
  & Published
  & $\times$
  & $\checkmark$
  & $\checkmark$
  & $\checkmark$
  & $\times$
  & $\checkmark$
  & Green
  & \makecell{Github\tablefootnotemark{2} \\ OSF \tablefootnotemark{3}}
\\
\addlinespace
4 & Curabitur dictum gravidamauris
  & John Smith
  & Conference
  & Published
  & $\times$
  & $\checkmark$
  & N/A
  & N/A
  & $\times$
  & $\times$ &
  $\times$
  & Github\tablefootnotemark{4}
\\
\addlinespace
5 & Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
    Donec vehicula augue eu neque
  & \makecell{John Smith \\ Jane Doe \\ Pierre Leblanc \\ Foo Bar \\ abc xyz}
  & \makecell[c]{Other \\ Journal}
  & \makecell[c]{Submitted\\(date)}
  & $\times$
  & $\checkmark$
  & $\checkmark$
  & $\times$
  & $\checkmark$
  & $\times$
  & --
  & \makecell{same as \\ above}
\\
\addlinespace
6 & Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectuset netus et malesuada
    fames ac turpis egesta
  & \makecell{Jane Doe \\ John Smith}
  & --
  & In Prep
  & $\checkmark$
  & $\checkmark$
  & $\checkmark$
  & N/A
  & --
  & --
  & --
  & OSF\tablefootnotemark{5}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\tablefootnotetext{1}{\url{https://onecvariusorciegetrisus}} \\
\tablefootnotetext{2}{\url{https://duisnibh micongueeuaccumsaneleifen}} \\
\tablefootnotetext{3}{\url{https://donecvariusorciegetrisus}} \\
\tablefootnotetext{4}{\url{https://Namduiligulafringillaa}} \\
\tablefootnotetext{5}{\url{https://praesentegetsemvelleoultricesbibendum}} \\
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}ll@{}}
$\checkmark$ & Available for this paper \\
$\times$     & Not possible or not available for this paper \\
N/A          & Not Applicable \\
--           & Work in progress
\end{tabular}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

I made some modifications, in particular the hyphen for “work in progress” should be a dash, but the main change is in the input which in the form I show can be maintained much more easily than with long lines.

The table is still too wide, actually, but I just want to give the idea.

[image]